# How can I target an :after psuedo-element within HTML controls rendered by an ASP.NET asp:checkbox control?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have seen code that applies to a simple input-label pair:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="checkbox" />  
<label for="toggle" class="switch"></label>
```

CSS

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.switch::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color: white;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.checkbox:checked + .switch::after {
  left : 20px;
}
.checkbox:checked + .switch {
  background-color: #7983ff;
}
.checkbox {
  display : none;
}
```

Working example from above:

https://codepen.io/lawrencelove/pen/xxBWpBj

But unfortunately, when using an ASP.NET `asp:checkbox` control, it renders the HTML differently.

HTML

```
<span class="checkbox"><input id="toggle" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ucSiteVersion$toggle" checked="checked">
</span>
<label for="toggle" class="switch"></label>
```

In this case, because the `input` control is nested within the `span` tags, and this seems to cause it to no longer match the combinator selector.

Broken example from above with the `span` tags:

https://codepen.io/lawrencelove/pen/MWxVrxm

I tried various combinations of adjacent siblings and descendants, but I couldn't get it to play nicely with the inclusion of the closing `span` tag.  I also tried referencing `#toggle:checked` instead of `.checkbox:checked`, but that didn't work either.

How can I target `.switch` from a `checkbox` control within the `span` tag?

Comment: Hi Lawrence, in addition to using the :has() CSS selector to select a parent element, you'll need change your selectors, as the checkbox class has moved from the input to the span.  My solution below is working in codepen!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
.checkbox:checked + .switch::after {
  left : 20px;
}
.checkbox:checked + .switch {
  background-color: #7983ff;
}
```

with this:

```
span:has(> input:checked) + .switch::after {
  left : 20px;
}
span:has(> input:checked) + .switch {
  background-color: #7983ff;
}
```